# Why isn't my navbar.css not showing up in localhost page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

I am enrolled in a full stack web development course and currently learning react on the side to build a project for my portfolio in hopes of getting into a front end web developer position.

Found this 2 year old tutorial in which I thought was a decent start to learn: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwarZBtFoFA&t=700s,  and this is my third hurdle that I haven't been able to get over.

No errors are showing up, I've tried changing tags around, moving/renaming, and searching for an answer but I can't seem to get the right one.

TIA

**components/Navbar.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Logo from '../images/HHlogo.jpg';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import "../styles/Navbar.css";

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div className="Navbar">
      <div className="leftSide">
        <img src={Logo} alt=',' />
      </div>
      <div className="rightSide">
        <Link to="/Home">Home </Link>
        <Link to="/About">About </Link>
        <Link to="/Classes">Classes </Link>
        <Link to="/Gallery">Gallery </Link>
        <Link to="/Trainer">Trainer </Link>
        <Link to="/Testimonial">Testimonial </Link>
        <Link to="/Contact">Contact </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navbar
```

**src/styles/Navbar.css**

```
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #121619;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.navbar .leftSide {
  flex: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 150px;
}

.navbar .leftSide img {
  width: 70px;
}

.navbar .rightSide {
  flex: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 20px;
}

.navbar .rightSide button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar .rightSide svg {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.navbar #open {
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.navbar #open img {
  display: none;
}

.navbar #close img {
  display: inherit;
}

.navbar #open .hiddenLinks {
  display: inherit;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.navbar #close .hiddenLinks {
  display: none;
}

.navbar #open a {
  width: 70px;
  margin: 5px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .navbar .rightSide a {
    width: 70px;
  }
  .navbar .leftSide {
    padding-left: 50px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar .rightSide a {
    display: none;
  }

  .navbar .rightSide {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-right: 50px;
  }

  .navbar .rightSide button {
    display: inherit;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .navbar .rightSide button {
    display: none;
  }

  .hiddenLinks {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

**src/App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>


  );
}

export default App;
```

**src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `className` specified in `Navbar` isn't consistent with the CSS. Identifiers are case-sensitive. Update `className="Navbar"` to `className="navbar"`.

Also, since you are using React-Router-DOM 6, the `Route` should use the `element` prop and pass JSX and there is no `exact` prop, e.g. `<Route path="/" element={<Home />} />`.

Answer (score 0):

you have `navbar` class in `css` but `Navbar` in `jsx` file fix it